# clear login details of user for each login

Tags: android, authentication

I am building an app and I want to clear user login details of Facebook for user.Because once it saves details it uses same details each time but I want is that it should ask user to login every time user opens the app ?

Comment: are you using facebook SDK or just opening the URL in webview?

Comment: m using facebook sdk..

Answer (score 1):

Write following statements along with Webview defined.

```
myWebView.clearCache(true);
myContext.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
myContext.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any jar and using library classes then following is the code snippet for your understanding.

From **Facebook.java**

Static variables that are used to call the activity for log in dialog.

```
 public static final int FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH = -1;

 private static final String LOGIN = "oauth";

 // Used as default activityCode by authorize(). See authorize() below.
 private static final int DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 32665;
```

following is the authorize method of this class to authorize a user and instead of using **DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE** if you use **FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH** your app will prompt you for log-in every time.

```
 /**
 * Authorize method that grants custom permissions.
 *
 * See authorize() below for @params.
 */
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        final DialogListener listener) {
    authorize(activity, permissions, DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE, listener);
}
```

another authorize method in this Facebook.java class is as follow and this method cause you for single sign on (SSO). For more information you can check this method's comments that I have included in this answer.

```
/**
 * Full authorize method.
 *
 * Starts either an Activity or a dialog which prompts the user to log in to
 * Facebook and grant the requested permissions to the given application.
 *
 * This method will, when possible, use Facebook's single sign-on for
 * Android to obtain an access token. This involves proxying a call through
 * the Facebook for Android stand-alone application, which will handle the
 * authentication flow, and return an OAuth access token for making API
 * calls.
 *
 * Because this process will not be available for all users, if single
 * sign-on is not possible, this method will automatically fall back to the
 * OAuth 2.0 User-Agent flow. In this flow, the user credentials are handled
 * by Facebook in an embedded WebView, not by the client application. As
 * such, the dialog makes a network request and renders HTML content rather
 * than a native UI. The access token is retrieved from a redirect to a
 * special URL that the WebView handles.
 *
 * Note that User credentials could be handled natively using the OAuth 2.0
 * Username and Password Flow, but this is not supported by this SDK.
 *
 * See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and
 * http://wiki.oauth.net/OAuth-2 for more details.
 *
 * Note that this method is asynchronous and the callback will be invoked in
 * the original calling thread (not in a background thread).
 *
 * Also note that requests may be made to the API without calling authorize
 * first, in which case only public information is returned.
 *
 * IMPORTANT: Note that single sign-on authentication will not function
 * correctly if you do not include a call to the authorizeCallback() method
 * in your onActivityResult() function! Please see below for more
 * information. single sign-on may be disabled by passing FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH
 * as the activityCode parameter in your call to authorize().
 *
 * @param activity
 *            The Android activity in which we want to display the
 *            authorization dialog.
 * @param applicationId
 *            The Facebook application identifier e.g. "350685531728"
 * @param permissions
 *            A list of permissions required for this application: e.g.
 *            "read_stream", "publish_stream", "offline_access", etc. see
 *            http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
 *            This parameter should not be null -- if you do not require any
 *            permissions, then pass in an empty String array.
 * @param activityCode
 *            Single sign-on requires an activity result to be called back
 *            to the client application -- if you are waiting on other
 *            activities to return data, pass a custom activity code here to
 *            avoid collisions. If you would like to force the use of legacy
 *            dialog-based authorization, pass FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH for this
 *            parameter. Otherwise just omit this parameter and Facebook
 *            will use a suitable default. See
 *            http://developer.android.com/reference/android/
 *              app/Activity.html for more information.
 * @param listener
 *            Callback interface for notifying the calling application when
 *            the authentication dialog has completed, failed, or been
 *            canceled.
 */
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
        int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

    boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

    mAuthDialogListener = listener;

    // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
    if (activityCode >= 0) {
        singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                permissions, activityCode);
    }
    // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
    if (!singleSignOnStarted) {
        startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

[image]

I am talking about the inline facebook library as shown above pic. you have to change from **DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE** to **FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH** to make your app to ask credential every time you request facebook.

Comment: Dinesh could you please elaborate it in more detail?

Comment: do you have facebook.java class within your project?

Comment: yes I do..but after making changes to it as you said,I am facing the same problem...

Comment: when you face some issue post your log by editing your question

Comment: If i do this then it gives me 'Unfortunately application has stopped' error.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Amit,

> When you login in facebook then facebook gave you "SessionId" and
>   facebook use this session every time.
>
> if you want every time login then you can write a "Logout" code at the
>   back button of Activity.

Comment: This answer is applied when you used Facebook SDk

Comment: Logout code is not working here,once it it gets login details for a user it stores them untill the app is uninstalled...